# Swift URL String encoding crashing on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, url-encoding

I have a URL string with variables appended to the end, like so:

```
.../create?title=My Apartment
```

I would like to escape any non-valid characters (like the space), but when I try to do so, I crash in both the simulator and on my device (iOS 8.0) using the following:

```
NSLog("Item1: \(item)")
NSLog("Item2: \(item.title)")

if let scrubbed = item.title.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) {
    NSLog("Scrubbed: \(scrubbed)")
} else {
    NSLog("Nope!")
}
```

What I see **on the simulator**, is this:

```
2014-09-24 16:59:19.120 MyApp[16406:171349] Item1: MyApp.PostItem
2014-09-24 16:59:19.121 MyApp[16406:171349] Item2: My Apartment
2014-09-24 16:59:19.125 MyApp[16406:171349] Scrubbed: My              0X0P+0partment
```

Note the strangeness of that scrubbed string. It crashes some time later complaining about a poorly-constructed `NSURL` object, unsurprisingly.

When I run this **on my device**, I crash with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the `NSLog()` statement that's trying to print `Scrubbed:`

```
2014-09-24 17:04:37.378 MyApp[4346:2048259] Item1: MyApp.PostItem
2014-09-24 17:04:37.379 MyApp[4346:2048259] Item2: My Apartment

(lldb) po scrubbed

error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: non-nominal type '$__lldb_context' cannot be extended
extension $__lldb_context {                            
^
<EXPR>:11:5: error: 'PostManager.Type' does not have a member named '$__lldb_wrapped_expr_3'
    $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_3(     
    ^                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
(lldb)
```

How can I figure out what's going on here? I would have expected to see `Nope!` printed in the console before having it crash like this.  The `String` value in the model object is being provided by a `UITextField`.

**Edit:** I was able to get some `NSData` output from the *pre-scrubbed* value:

```
NSLog("Data: \(item.title.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false))")
...
2014-09-24 17:18:43.620 MyApp[4367:2051348] Data: Optional(<4d792041 70617274 6d656e74>)
```

**Edit 2:** I can confirm this **crashes** in Xcode, and **passes** in a playground. Seems to be a bug - but where? Xcode? Compiler? Runtime?

**Edit 3:** This bug only crops up if I attempt to print out the variable value with `NSLog()`. If I completely avoid doing this, and just *use* the variable, everybody's happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like escaping with `NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()` generates strange unicode string which forces crash in NSLog in case using this string as first parameter.

There are a few ways to avoid this and you definitely should use them:

- As far as you are using this in URL query you definitely should use different characher set - `NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()`.
- Use `print/println`
- Pass `scrubbed` to `NSLog` as a parameter `NSLog("Scrubbed: %@", scrubbed)`

Any of those "workarounds" solves the problem.